# Elasticsearch: What the difference in performance when using one index versus multiple indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have 100 tables and I want to put them in Elasticsearch. Each table has 10 fields and there are 10 million rows of data in these 100 tables.

What the difference in performance if I put each table into a different index or put all the tables in one index with 1000 fields?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how closely related your tables are. Lets take both the scenarios one by one.

**1. All the 10 tables in different Indices:** If all the tables are not related to each other, i.e. search operations can be performed individually to all the tables and you will not need to join these tables to get the required results, this is a better option to create individual index for all of them as the data will be distributed and search operation should be faster.

**2. All tables in one index with 1000 fields:** If your tables are related and you will need to perform join operations to get the desired result for the search operation, it should be better to denormalize your data model to fit all the 1000 fields in one index. Joining Indices during search operation in Elasticsearch are costly.

Please refer the [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/denormalization.html) for further clarifications.